# Prove the inequality $\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+a+b}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{a^2+b+c}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{b^2+c+a} \ge 2$

Tags: inequality, fractions, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

For every $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=1$ prove the inequality 
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+a+b}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{a^2+b+c}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{b^2+c+a} \ge 2$$

**My work so far:**

$abc=1 \Rightarrow \frac 13 (a+b+c)\ge 1$
Then $$c^2+a+b \le c^2+(a+b)\frac 13(a+b+c)$$

Or more
$$ (\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+a+b}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{a^2+b+c}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{b^2+c+a})((c^2+a+b)+(a^2+b+c)+(b^2+c+a)) \ge $$
$$\ge(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2})^2$$

Comment: What inequalities have you tried? A good thing to know in inequalities is when equality holds - it might give you a hint on what inequality to use and/or to not use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=x^3$, $b=y^3$ and $c=z^3$.
Hence, by Muirhead $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+a+b}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^6+y^6}{z^6+xyz(x^3+y^3)}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^6+y^6}{z^6+z(x^5+y^5)}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^7y+x^7z)}{xyz(x^5+y^5+z^5)}\geq2$

Comment: What is the Muirhead step here? it's true that $\sum_{cyc} z(x^5+y^5) \ge \sum_{cyc} xyz(x^3+y^3)$, but this is not what you are using.

Comment: @user31415 6 $x^5+y^5\geq xy(x^3+y^3)$

Comment: I see, thanks! Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

As we know:
$$2ab \le a^{2}+b^{2} $$, and
$$3a^{\frac{1}{3}} = 3(a^{2}bc)^{\frac{1}{3}} \le a^{2} + b + c $$ (because of $abc =1$)

Now we have :
$$2(\frac{ab}{3c^{1/3}} + \frac{ac}{3b^{1/3}} +\frac{cb}{3a^{1/3}})$$
 Now using Cauchy we could prove our inequality.

Comment: If you have $a^2+b+c$ is greater than something, how can you conclude that the fraction, with $a^2+b+c$ in the denominator, is greater than something?

Comment: @user31415 yes, because of I compare only $a^{2}+b+c$

Comment: @openspace If $a^2+b+c\ge 3\left(a^2bc\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, then it's not true that $\frac{2bc}{a^2+b+c}\ge \frac{2bc}{3\left(a^2bc\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

Comment: I guess I didn't make myself clear. You claimed that $a^2+b+c \ge 3a^{1/3}$, so $\frac{b^2+c^2}{a^2+b+c} \ge \frac{b^2+c^2}{3a^{1/3}}$. This is false - you reversed the sign.